# Input type="time" binding of value attribute doesn't update the UI with angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I have an `input` tag of `type="time"` as below

```
<input type='time' id='from' ng-model='data.hall.occupancy.timeRange.from' datify value="{{data.hall.occupancy.timeRange.from | propertime}}"/>
```

the filter and directive are as follows

```
 app.directive('datify',function(){
return {
    require:'ngModel',
    link:function(scope,element,attrs,modelCtrl){
        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue){
            var times = inputValue.split(":");
            var hours = times[0];
            var mins = times[1];
            var currentDate = new Date();
            var outputDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(),currentDate.getMonth(),currentDate.getDate(),hours,mins);
            return outputDate.toString();
        });
    }
};
});

app.filter('propertime',function(){
return function(timeStamp){
    if(timeStamp){
        var dateObj = new Date(timeStamp.toString());
        var date = dateObj.getDate();
        var month = dateObj.getMonth()+1;
        var year = dateObj.getFullYear();
        var hours = (0+ dateObj.getHours().toString()).slice(-2);
        var minutes = (0+ dateObj.getMinutes().toString()).slice(-2);
        return hours+":"+minutes;//+" "+date+"/"+month+"/"+year;
    }
}
});
```

Link to my plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/G4G5V62Y70IBvXUXdvQT?p=preview

The `value` attribute of `input` tag is updated in DOM correctly, but doesn't affect the UI. However updating the time in the UI, updates the `value` attribute in the DOM. Can someone tell me what is happening here.

**Note: I am using Chrome (Firefox shows input type="time" as a normal text input)**

Answer (score 2):

We're trying to create a directive/component that needs to interact with another directive (`ng-model` in this case).

So we wrote `require: 'ngModel',`

After we parse input `$parse(attrs.datify);`

**HTML**

```
<input 
       type='time'
       id='from' 
        datify='data.hall.occupancy.timeRange.from' 
        ng-model='data.hall.occupancy.timeRange.from'
        value="{{data.hall.occupancy.timeRange.from | propertime}}"
 />
```

**Directive**

```
   app.directive('datify', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.datify);

            scope.$watch(model, function (value) {
                if (value.toString().split(":").length == 2) {
                    backToDate(value)
                }
            }); // end watch

            function backToDate(value) {
                var times = value.split(":");
                var hours = times[0];
                var mins = times[1];
                var currentDate = new Date();
                var outputDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDay(), hours, mins);
                modelCtrl.$setViewValue(outputDate);
            }

            function validate(value) {
                console.log('into validate');
                var otherFieldValue = model(scope);
                //console.log('validate:', value, otherFieldValue);

                var times = value.toString().split(":");

                var hours = times[1];
                var mins = times[2].split(".")[0];
                var currentDate = new Date();

                var outputDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDay(), hours, mins);
                //console.log("the date:", outputDate.toString());
                modelCtrl.$setViewValue(outputDate);
                return outputDate;
            }

            modelCtrl.$formatters.push(validate);
        }
    };
});
```

Fixed Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/631/)</kbd>

Comment: When I change my model, it doesn't update the UI. Click on Change button, you would know what I mean. Why is that?

Comment: what do u expect from pressing on change button?

Comment: do u switch between to-from?

Comment: for the demo, I am just changing to some other value (in this case I copied the value in the To field). In real, I am changing the data.hall object based on a <select> option.

Comment: if you want to change `input` value on change `data.hall`, add `$watch` to link that listens on `data.hall` change

Comment: And I will use the datify directive on other input tags with different ngModel, and not only for data.hall.occupancy.timeRange.from model, so how can I $setViewValue for the model to which I am applying the directive to.

Comment: see my edit, posted new Plunker, Havent time right now to play but this is direction

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39630/discussion-between-vignesh-pt-and-maxim-shoustin)

Comment: it almost works, but updating time in the view, doesn't update the model. And if you had some patience, it would be great if you could give a small explanation on what is 'newval', and its purpose. Thanks a ton for the help so far.

Comment: why does the use of ng-model for this input tag, make it not to work?

Comment: Sorry for delay, I changed my code regards to what you wanted I hope, see new Plunker.

Comment: But this changes my model's (data.hall.occupancy.timeRange.from) to this format (hh:mm), when I change the value through the UI. I do not want this to happen, and want the full date information in the model. Is this possible. I suppose we should have $parsers. Am I correct?

Comment: Well, you have `$watch` for that, see Fiddle added

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about angular, but Date/time input type will be supported in Chrome, Opera and iOS Safari. http://caniuse.com/input-datetime